# withEvents variable 'PreviousPage' conflicts with property 'PreviousPage' in the base class 'Page' and should be declared 'Shadows'

Tags: vb.net

I am converting an application from vb.net 2003 to 2005. I got the following warning and need help how to resolve it.

withEvents variable 'PreviousPage' conflicts with property 'PreviousPage' in the base class 'Page' and should be declared 'Shadows'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The base Page class has a property called PreviousPage.

Do you have a control on this form with that name (the "WithEvents variable" referred to in the error)?  It is conflicting with the base class.

Comment: Yes I have a control with this name.

Comment: The name of the control will need to change, as it conflicts with the base class property introduced in the 2.0 framework.